# Opencv 3.0.0 extra modules not found

Tags: git, opencv, ubuntu

I'm using OpenCV 3.0.0 in ubuntu linux console.

I need to use SURF, but i've read that it's not included in the main OpenCV installation, so i've followed the opencv_contrib GIT steps:

1) I successfully cloned opencv_contrib in my ubuntu

2) I run "cmake -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/ubuntu/opencv/opencv_contrib/modules/ /home/ubuntu/opencv/". No errors. Everything fine.

3)make -j5. I get exactly the same errors than when i didn't cloned opencv_contrib ( error: no matching function for call to ‘cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::SURF(int&)’)

I've read [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/issues/107) that some versions of opencv_contrib dosen't work with opencv 3.0.0

Any idea if this is my problem?
Am i doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

with opencv3.0, you can't make an instance of SURF or SIFT on the 'stack' anymore.

use:

```
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d"

cv::Ptr<cv::xfeatures2d::SURF> surf = cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create(...);
surf->detect(...);
```

and link: opencv_xfeatures2d300

(and i don't think, the mentionend github issue is related to your problem)

Comment: Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create(...) returns me "undefined reference to `cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create(double, int, int, bool, bool)'" error.

Comment: ^^ sorry, forgot to mention: link  opencv_xfeatures2d300

Comment: both dll(so) and lib(a) should have been build when you did a rebuild with the opencv_contrib repo. dll on the internet ? i doubt so.

Comment: Well, i don't have those files, so maybe i have to take a step back  and confirm that my rebuild was really done.
And yes, i found and downloaded "opencv_xfeatures2d300.dll".

Comment: yes, go back to the cmake pass, and check the outcome carefully. (and the windows-dll won't help you much on linux)